# Android update SQLite table entry

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, updates

I have a local SQLite Database in may App. I create and open the Database like this:

```
CookieClickerBase = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(CookieBase, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
CookieClickerBase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cookiedata(what TEXT, data LONG)");
```

I insert some thin into the table link this:

```
CookieClickerBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO cookiedata VALUES ('Image','3')");
```

But now I wont to change the data from 3 to 9 in the table entry, where what = Image.
How can I do that?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `UPDATE` statement with `execSQL()`:

```
CookieClickerBase.execSQL("UPDATE cookiedata SET data = 9 WHERE what ='Image'");
```

or use the recommended method which is `update()` with `ContentValues`:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("data", "9");
int rows = CookieClickerBase.update("cookiedata", cv, "what = ?", new String[] {"Image"});
```

The variable `rows` will contain the number of updated rows.